# Get sum of fields for items that have their checkbox ticked for express js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a list of food items and I want to be able to select items from the list by ticking the corresponding checkboxes and then calculating the sum of their fields e.g. I have the fields called calories, carbs, fat, protein, salt, sugar and if I select two items in the list and click the calculate button, it will print the sum of calories, carbs, fat, protein, salt, sugar for the two items.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>List foods page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> List foods page </h1>
<h3>Display all foods stored in the database including name, typical values, unit of the typical value, calories, carbs, fat, protein, salt, and sugar of the food item here:</h3>
<ul>
<% availableFood.forEach(function(food_item){ %>
        <form method="POST" action="/topic7/mid-term/calculate">
                <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value=<%= food_item.name %>>
                <input id="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="quantity"/>
                <%= food_item.name %>, <%= food_item.typical_values %>, 
                <%= food_item.unit_of_the_typical_value %>, <%= food_item.calories %>, 
                <%= food_item.carbs %>, <%= food_item.fat %>, <%= food_item.protein %>, 
                <%= food_item.salt %>, <%= food_item.sugar %></p>
        </form>
<% }) %>
<form method="POST" action="/topic7/mid-term/calculate">
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate sum" />
</form>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

```
app.post("/calculate", function (req, res) {
        let sqlquery = "SELECT SUM(calories, carbs, fat, protein, salt, sugar) FROM food_item WHERE name = ?";
        let sum = [req.body.checkbox];

        db.query(sqlquery, sum, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
            }else{
                res.send(" The nutritional information and calorie count of a recipe or a meal is: " + result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a set instead of a single value in the SQL statement and compare with `IN` instead of `=`.

The sums need to be calculated separately. Give them names with `AS` to make the result easier to read.

```
let sqlquery = "SELECT SUM(calories) AS calories, SUM(carbs) AS carbs, SUM(fat) AS fat FROM food_item WHERE name IN (?)";
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have a problem where I'm not getting the value of the checkboxes since the result.message is undefined. How do I let the calculate button get the value of the checkboxes? If I put the button within the same form as the checkbox, it can only return the checkbox value for one checkbox but I want it to return the checkbox value for multiple checkboxes.

Comment: It sends all values in a query string, for example `checkbox=food1&checkbox=food2&checkbox=food3`. In NodeJS, `bodyParser.urlencoded` places an array in `req.body.checkbox` in this case. Which body parser do you use if this doesn't work for you?

Comment: I use this `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` in my js file. Is there nothing wrong with the form I posted above? I thought there might be something wrong with it since it's telling me the result is undefined. Or is `res.send` printing out the wrong thing?

Comment: If you are unsure where the problem is, do a `console.log` or try to send back `req.body.checkbox` directly to check if that works. If the result is undefined, there seems to be a problem with the query. Which database do you use? I tested my answer with MySQL. And did you updated the query according to my answer? Additionally, try to res.send just the result, omit the string concatenation.

Comment: I sent back `req.body.checkbox` and it does give me the name but only for one entry, even if multiple entries have their checkbox ticked. I'm using mysql database. Ye I updated my query according to your answer. Sending just the result also gives undefind.

Comment: Multiple checkboxes work for me (and the query does too). Try to split this question into two new ones (get an array with all checkboxes, do a database query when you have the array). And provide complete examples for each one (including how to create the database for the second question, ...).

Comment: I updated the question with the full html for my form, can you see if there's any mistakes there? Also, if I `res.send` result instead of result.message, I get the output [object Object]. Do you know what that means.

Comment: result.message is most likely wrong. You need just result, as it is written originally in your question. `[object Object]` is because of string concatenation. That's why I said to remove it, then it will send the object data. If you really want to keep it, you need to use `"Data: " + JSON.stringify(result)`.

Comment: OK it works now but I still have the problem that it only shows the result for one checkbox, even if I select two checkboxes.